# Monge–Ampère equation with polynomials

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, polynomials, real-algebraic-geometry

Let $P$ be a real polynomial of $n$ variables. Does the Monge–Ampère equation
$$
\det D^2 Q=P
$$
always have a (global) real polynomial solution $Q$?

I think this should be something standard, but I am unable to find any reference. The following paper addresses the case when $n=2$, but I am uncertain about higher dimensional cases.

[Aminov - Polynomial solutions of the Monge–Ampère equation](https://www.osti.gov/biblio/22364218) ([DOI link](https://doi.org/10.1070/SM2014v205n11ABEH004428)).

Comment: The paper you refer to says that a polynomial solution does NOT always exist, even in two variables. The author gives a necessary and sufficient condition. So what is your question?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I am interested in a general way of finding one particular solution to this in higher dimensions, provided it exists. For example, if $P(x,y,z)=z-R(x,y)$, does there always exist a solution $Q$ to $\det D^2 Q=P$? If yes, is there an efficient way to find at least one solution?